# Seeking Additional Funding During PhD: Feasibility and Variations Across Universities and Countries

Tags: phd, research-process, graduate-school, funding, academic-life

In the midst of PhD journey, can someone contemplate the feasibility and norms around seeking additional funding in the second or third year? This could be for various reasons such as increased research expenses, personal financial needs, or unforeseen project expansions, but my question is:

Is it common or even possible for PhD students to request additional funding after their initial funding arrangement? How is this typically approached?

Comment: This very strongly country dependent. What country are you asking about?

Comment: The USA. @TimRias

Comment: To (potentially) increase your income there may be fellowships to apply for. The other things are research funding that is up to your advisor and their grant funding. If the initial pay is not enough, don’t go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are funded through a teaching assistantship, that will be decided at the department/college level and will represent a fixed value, which usually scales slightly every year with inflation (but usually doesn't keep up with it).

If you are funded through a Professor's grant, then it is basically the same thing, but there is a bit more leeway to negotiate, but often not much as these numbers are predetermined when you apply for the grant. So if you want to pay a student more, it usually means the grant runs out faster, or you may be dipping into another salary stream under that grant. Grant contracts for graduate students are typically for 20 hours/week, so there may be opportunity to take on a bit extra by taking on small departmental responsibilities, an extra teaching load, etc...

Performance-based raises by your PI for doing well are extremely rare, because mainly we do not have an infrastructure to do that. I typically manage to do that when my overhead coffers are full (which on my end means my students earn an extra 3K during the summer or something small like that), but that is cyclical and not a reliable source. That money is better spent sending students to as many conferences as I can afford to.

Fellowships are the way to get the biggest bump, but in the US the options for internationals are limited.

Unfortunately, for internationals, overall, the situation can be very difficult, even more-so depending on country of origin (particularly if you are from China, Russia, Iran, Cuba, Venezuela, North Korea, and Syria), as that can limit participation in certain grants, or even certain labs (I legally had to keep manuals locked away from a Chinese postdoc for doing a particular brand of semiconductor work in the past).

So moral of the story, if you are an international, make sure you are happy with the base stipend when you go in, because you may not have as many options to raise it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you ask about the situation across countries, for postgraduate students (both research and taught) at UK universities, support funds typically exist for *unexpected* financial emergencies with regard to living costs, potentially including tuition fees, either in parallel to or from the same pot as undergraduate students. Speaking in general these schemes:

- get significantly more requests for support than they can fully meet
- require appropriate evidence of a change of circumstances such that the original funding plan the student arrived with no longer works
- won't cover research expenses, which would generally be expected to be covered by the department or the student's scholarship.
- Only cover the 3-3.5 years a UK PhD is expected to take, with perhaps limited support in the final 6 month "writing up" period.

In terms of primary funding, holding more than one scholarship, or trying to vary the terms of the scholarship after starting would both be unusal. Note that in the UK, ancillary teaching is a side-hustle for PhD students, not a primary source of income. Financial pressures, and thus the percentage of students applying generally varies with the economic climate (local & global), and appears to be on a down-swing at the moment.

Some example funds at [Cambridge](https://www.cambridgestudents.cam.ac.uk/fees-and-funding/financial-assistance/postgraduate-financial-assistance-fund), [Imperial](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/students/fees-and-funding/financial-assistance/student-support-fund/) and [St. Andrews](https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/students/money/financialsupport/discretionary-fund/).